# Delphi: How to set TWebResponse to contain gzip and read it in Android App?

Tags: android, delphi, webserver

I'm building a WebServer for Android App.(WebBroker->VC).

How can I compress my response string to gzip, I tried this:

```
 a:=[{.......}];//json data
 srcbuf := BytesOf(a.ToString);
 ZCompress(srcbuf, destbuf, zcDefault);
 Response.Content := '';
 Response.ContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
 Response.ContentEncoding := 'deflate';
 Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
 Response.ContentStream.Write(@(destbuf[0]),length(destbuf));
 Response.ContentLength := (length(destbuf));
```

In my android app I get error:

**Uknown format (magic number...)**

I also have server side written in PHP and android app works fine, I think that Delphi System.ZLib doesn't compress as gzip?

Any idea how solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

**Delphi:**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
procedure doGZIP(Input, gZipped: TMemoryStream);//helper function
const
  GZIP = 31;//very important because gzip is a linux zip format
var
  CompactadorGZip: TZCompressionStream;
begin
  Input.Position:=0;
  CompactadorGZip:=TZCompressionStream.Create(gZipped, zcMax, GZIP);
  CompactadorGZip.CopyFrom(Input, Input.Size);
  CompactadorGZip.Free;
  gZipped.Position:=0;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
strJSON:=a.ToString;//a->TJSONArray
 //init
 Original:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 gZIPStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
 //copy result to stream
 oString := UTF8String(strJSON);
 len := length(oString);
 Original.WriteBuffer(oString[1], len);
 //make it gzip
 doGZIP(Original,gZIPStream);
 //prepare responsestream and set content encoding and type
 Response.Content := '';
 Response.ContentStream:=gZIPStream;
 Response.ContentEncoding := 'gzip';
 Response.ContentType := 'application/json';
 //clear...
 Original.Free;
```

**Android:**

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");//do not forget this
```